# Python: Simplify many if-statements

Tags: python, if-statement, binary-tree, traversal

I have a function that traverses a tree and returns the elements as a list. Is there a way to simplify all the if statements in `treeToList::traverse`, because it looks sort of redundant?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def enum(**enums):
  return type('Enum', (), enums)

Order = enum(PREORDER=0, INORDER=1, POSTORDER=2)
def treeToList(root, order=Order.INORDER):
  ret = list()
  def traverse(node, order):
    if order == Order.PREORDER: ret.append(node.data)
    if node.right != None: traverse(node.right, order)
    if order == Order.INORDER: ret.append(node.data)
    if node.down != None: traverse(node.down, order)
    if order == Order.POSTORDER: ret.append(node.data)
  traverse(root, order)
  return ret

class node:
  def __init__(self, data=None):
    self.data = data
    self.down = None
    self.right = None

if __name__ == '__main__':
  root = node('F')
  root.right = node('B')
  root.down = node('G')
  root.right.right = node('A')
  root.right.down = node('D')
  root.down.down = node('I')
  root.right.down.right = node('C')
  root.right.down.down = node('E')
  root.down.down.right = node('H')

  print treeToList(root, Order.PREORDER)
  print treeToList(root, Order.INORDER)
  print treeToList(root, Order.POSTORDER)
```

**Output**

```
['F', 'B', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'E', 'G', 'I', 'H']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I']
['A', 'C', 'E', 'D', 'B', 'H', 'I', 'G', 'F']
```

Comment: +1 for including a test suite with a refactor request :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if you get rid of the closure.. a pure function is probably clearer:

```
def treeToList(node, order=Order.INORDER):
    if node is None:
        return []

    right = treeToList(node.right, order)
    down = treeToList(node.down, order)
    current = [node.data]

    if order == Order.PREORDER:
        return current + right + down

    if order == Order.INORDER:
        return right + current + down

    if order == Order.POSTORDER:
        return right + down + current
```

but builds a lot of intermediate lists of course.

Comment: +1. This is exactly what I meant by my last paragraph. I think it was easier to write in Python than in English. (It's certainly easier to understand that way.)

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that comes to my mind is this:

```
def treeToList(root, order=Order.INORDER):
    ret = list()
    def inorder_traversal(node):
        if node is not None:
            inorder_traversal(node.right)
            ret.append(node.data)
            inorder_traversal(node.down)

    def preorder_traversal(node):
        if node is not None:
            ret.append(node.data)
            preorder_traversal(node.right)
            preorder_traversal(node.down)

    def postorder_traversal(node):
        if node is not None:
            postorder_traversal(node.right)
            postorder_traversal(node.down)
            ret.append(node.data)

    if order == Order.PREORDER:
        preorder_traversal(node)
    elif order == Order.INORDER:
        inorder_traversal(node)
    else:
        postorder_traversal(node)

    return ret
```

Comment: not really a simplification though... but neater in a way, so +1.

Comment: I'd argue that it's more clear that each traversal is implemented correctly here than in the original question. But yeah, there's not much that can be done to clarify this code.

Comment: If you really want: `(preorder_traversal, inorder_traversal, postorder_traversal)[order](node)` will actually make this "simpler"… but obviously less readable.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a good way to eliminate the three `if order` statements without reorganizing the algorithm. The position at which `ret.append` happens is dependent on the value, so you pretty much have to check it all three times, one way or another.

But there's one obvious way to reorganize things to remove a couple `if`s:

```
def traverse(node, order):
    if node is None: return
    if order == Order.PREORDER: ret.append(node.data)
    traverse(node.right, order)
    if order == Order.INORDER: ret.append(node.data)
    traverse(node.down, order)
    if order == Order.POSTORDER: ret.append(node.data)
```

Of course it's one line longer, but it's only 4 `if`s instead of 6.

Another possibility is to change things to keep track of all three positions, and insert into the appropriate position after the fact:

```
def traverse(node, order):
    if node is None: return
    prepos = len(ret)
    traverse(node.right, order)
    inpos = len(ret)
    traverse(node.down, order)
    postpos = len(ret)
    pos = (prepos, inpos, postpos)[order]
    ret[pos:pos+1] = node.data
```

This removes all of the `if`s, but I don't think the result is exactly easier to read or comprehend…

Really, the way to make this easier to read and comprehend is probably to switch to a functional algorithm (recursive mutable algorithms are rarely fun to think through)… but that's just going to make the three `if` bodies larger, not get rid of them.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Try something like</strike>

```
if order in (Order.PREORDER, Order.INORDER, ...):
    ret.append(node.data)
```

*Nitpicks*

You should have your conditions on multiple lines

```
if cond:
    pass
```

instead of

```
if cond: pass
```

also consider using `is` and `is not` when comparing to `None` instead of `==` and `!=`.

Comment: same issue as previous (now deleted) answer: the order of the conditions IS important... what you suggest changes that order.

Comment: @isedev, +1 you're right, I'll leave it so others don't make the same mistake.

Comment: fair enough, can't remove the -1 (wasn't me).